# Updating products on backend doesn't reflect on frontend

Tags: magento2.4, varnish, apache, apache2

I have this magento store I just installed and configured according to guides Varnish cache.

Website now is blazing fast, but if I update a product (for example, add a description), even if I cache clean/flush, invalidate indexes and reindex, product page still shows stale data (ie none of the changes I just made).

How can I make sure that, anytime I update a product, I either invalidate/redo the cache for that product?

Comment: did you try to purge Varnish? find a way to purge Varnish.

Comment: have you configured the varnish acl correctly specifically acl purge list? Saving a product should always invalidate the varnish cache for that product.

Comment: If I post my /etc/varnish/default.vcl can you help me understand if I did it right, @paj?

Comment: When you load the page, open your js console and click on the "network" tab. Look for the entry which is the page (not images, js files, etc). Usually the first entry in the list but you can also use the "Doc" filter to find it. Check the response headers and see if the cache headers not HIT or MISS

Answer (score 0):

### Ban & purge

The standard Magento VCL configuration has logic inside the `vcl_recv` subroutine to invalidate the cache. This uses the `ban` VCL function.

Here's an extract:

```
if (req.http.host && req.http.host != "" && req.http.host != "127.0.0.1") {
    ban("obj.http.X-Host ~ " + req.http.host + " && obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
} else {
    ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);}
```

When changes are made in your backend, and a ban is triggered, you can run the following command to display the so-called ban list:

```
varnishadm ban.list
```

This will list all attempts to ban content from the cache, and it uses ban expressions to match patterns of objects.

> Please check the ban list. When in doubt, share ban list entries immediately after changing content in the Magento backend. This will allow me to judge whether or not something was wrong.

### Debug using the Age header

If it turns out that a ban was successful, the matching objects wil be removed from cache. The `Age` response header reflects the age of objects in cache.

A successful ban will result in an `Age: 0` header. Please look out for this

### Debug using varnishlog

The `varnishlog` utility is an in-depth logging tool that gives you insight in what happens to each request.

Run the following command for the page you want to monitor:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"
```

Then update some product settings in your backend, and then open the page again. You'll see how Varnish behaves by looking at the logs.

You can also monitor the effectiveness of the ban itself by running the following command:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqMethod eq 'PURGE'"
```

The logs will also be quite explicit on what happened to the ban.

When you're having a tough time interpreting the output of these logs, have a look at the blog post I wrote about `varnishlog`: https://feryn.eu/blog/varnishlog-measure-varnish-cache-performance/